# Semi automatic classification plugin, downloading sentinel 2, authentication problem

Tags: qgis-plugins, sentinel-2

When I try to find a Sentinel 2 image for download with this plug in, it asks me about my credentials, I enter them, but nothing happens.

On the ESA page, I can login, no problem.

I use OSX 10.8.5 and QGIS 2.14.8

How do you download Sentinel 2 imagery with this plug in? Why doesn't it work for me? 
Can I download the images directly from the ESA page and then upload them into QGIS and the plug in?

Comment: I use OSX 10.8.5 and QGIS 2.14.8

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question whenever you wish to revise it with any additional details.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to change the service's URL to `https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/` ?

Answer (score 0):

I recently did a bunch of image classification using Sentinel imagery and the Semi-Automatic Classification Plug-in with QGIS 2.14. I downloaded the imagery directly from the scihub portal at https://scihub.copernicus.eu/ , and it worked fine for futher processing with the SACP (as well as in ArcGIS).

In October this year, the Sentinel portal was frequently down for maintenance. It could be that the site is currently down, but the plugin doesn't tell you this. I had to make several attempts over the course of a week or so to get the imagery I wanted. Alternately there could be a bug with the plugin itself, but this is harder to check.

I would just go directly to the portal and get your imagery there, and import your imagery into QGIS after - worked fine for me!